# How often locust swarm jumps?

Tags: diablo-iii

I also wonder how often they jump. Once per second? Once per tick? What's the point of jumping to 2 enemies in pestilence then if every enemies will get infected anyway?

This is for witch doctor skill locus swarm

Comment: I can't answer off-hand about how often it normally jumps (I believe there's a fairly decent chance to jump each second... maybe 50%, but I can't say for certain), but I will say that the difference for the rune that jumps to 2 enemies instead of one is barely noticeable.

Comment: The description says it jumps when the enemy dies. I believe it jumps far more often than that.

Answer (score 3):

Locust swarms jump once per tick, to a maximum range of 20 yards.

Locust swarms with pestilence jump twice, to a maximum range of 20 yards.

In the end, yes, in most cases your regular pestilence is going to end up effecting all the enemies within range. The difference is in how quickly the locusts spread between targets.

If you have 20 enemies within range of your attack, it will take 20 ticks (including the cast) before all enemies are under the effect of a regular locust swarm.

With pestilence, up to 32 enemies can be hit within 6 ticks, as consecutive ticks allows for potentially doubling that amount of enemies hit with the previous tick.

If you are dealing with a few tougher enemies, there is real difference. It would be more effective to use a different rune to improve damage or offer another combat benefit. If you are dealing with a lot of enemies, this rune will allow you to hit all of them at a much faster rate.

Comment: So it jumps per tick or when the enemy died?

Comment: @JimThio, tick..